# PHP mail form not functioning

Tags: forms, email, submission

I am using a Templatemo template and attempting to get the Email Form Submission to function.
(Signaturetables.com is the site)
I have downloaded the correct contact.php form from templatemo and followed instructions, and modified it all accordingly to info@signaturtables.com.
Can anyone see what is my problem?

I have contacted GoDaddy regarding this. They are hosting Signaturetables.com. They say they cannot even see emails being sent from the mail area.
They are suggesting the error is then on the php page.
This is over my head and I need help!
Thanks to anyone who can shed light on this for me!

HERE IS MY INDEX.HTML PAGE FORM SUBMISSION CODE:

```
<div class="templatemo_lightgrey" id="templatemo_contact">
    <div class="templatemo_paracenter">
    <h2>Contact us</h2></div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="templatemo_paracenter">
        Please feel free to call or e-mail for inquiries.
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="templatemo_maps">
          <div class="fluid-wrapper">
            <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d2965.3996287541227!2d-91.66233118455531!3d41.99169827921325!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x87e4f0b4219cc027%3A0xe64b0645b30a6bc!2sSignature+Santiago!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sus!4v1479248142906" width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe> 
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>



   <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3">

        <form action="contact.php" method="post" id="form" class="contact-form">


          <div class="form-group">
            <input name="cf_name" type="text" class="form-control" id="fullname" placeholder="Your Name" maxlength="30">
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <input name="cf_email" type="text" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Your Email" maxlength="30">
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <input name="subject" type="text" class="form-control" id="subject" placeholder="Your Subject" maxlength="40">
          </div>

          <div><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Send Message</button></div>

        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-9">
        <div class="txtarea">
          <textarea name="cf_message" rows="10" class="form-control" id="message"></textarea>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>



    </div>
  </div>
    </div>
```

---

Comment: have you configure any email server on your domain??

Comment: I dont know how to do this. GoDaddy tells me all php files will work fine on their server